# Gyroscope behaving differently between Samsung and Google Pixel

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, gyroscope

I wanted to control the camera with the gyroscope of Unity and I saw the code on another post here on how to do that. But the behaviour is different between the Google Pixel and Samsung S7 I have to test the app. It seems that the same scene with the same code is flipped about 180 degrees along one of the axis.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;
public class GyroControl : MonoBehaviour {


 private bool gyroEnabled;
 private Gyroscope gyroscope;

 private GameObject cameraContainer;
 private Quaternion rotation;

 void Start () {

     cameraContainer = new GameObject ("Camera Container");
     cameraContainer.transform.position = transform.position;
     transform.SetParent (cameraContainer.transform);

     Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;

     gyroEnabled = EnableGyro ();

 }

 private bool EnableGyro() {
     if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope) {
         gyroscope = Input.gyro;
         gyroscope.enabled = true;

         cameraContainer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
         rotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, 1, 0);

         return true;
     }

     return false;
 }

 void Update () {
     if (gyroEnabled) {
         transform.localRotation = gyroscope.attitude * rotation;
     }

 }
```

}
code here

Comment: Unfortunately the gyroscopes and the way they report (and how that reporting is handled) varies from phone to phone, and between OS versions, too. So you will find all sorts of oddities like this, between different models within the same brand, too. The only way to deal with this is find out how each is different, and make allowance for that in the defines that determine the phone being used at the start.